# Mifare, math challenge

Tags: vb.net, hex, decimal, rfid, mifare

I have two types of readers for RFID at work. One is for access control, and are wall mounted with LCD display conneted to a server, and one USB WaveID, pcProx reader.

When i read a mifare card 1K with the USB reader or the NFC reader in my andriod phone i get:

```
HEX: 08 E5 2A 46 (reversed)
DEC: 149236294
```

But when i read the same card in the wall mounted reader i get:

```
HEX: 42 6C 87 A3 
DEC: 1114408867
```

and this number is the only number the security software accept to grant access.

I have the computer to register new cards at my desk, and the wall mounted reader is at a diffrent location at work. I can't move to that location or move the wall mounted reader to my room.

I have contacted the Company that deliverd our security system, but they can't tell me or don't know how the system work, because the only explanation i got is the system reads the mifare card reversed.

Now, i don't know if this is a math problem, but first i thought there was some kind of offset, but this problem is not that easy.

Have six old cards with there numbers, if someone would like to try to "crack" this.

```
pcProx/NFC       Wall mounted
149236294        1114408867
149331526        4083838560
149829318        1819815912
149761094        1167209387
3349747860       4273657149
3349830260       2599240414
```

I would love to write my own software in vb.net to "translate" the numbers, that would save me so much time.

Comment: Are you sure both readers are reading from the same block?

Comment: Agree with Pure. This doesn't appear to be the same data just reversed (whether by bytes or bits).

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. i also have a Arduino with a RFID-RC522 reader. One arduino Project can dump whole card, and Block 0 is the only one contains any data.
HEX of block one of the first card above:
    46 2A E5 08 81 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69

Comment: And block 1 to 15 sector 0 look like this:
00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF

Comment: The `46 2A E5 08` is byte reversed of the one value. I have no idea where that other reader is getting `42 6C 87 A3` from either of those values.